# How to access a database

Tags: c#, sql

My second day with Visual C# (after years of PHP), and I am trying to access an SQL database.

I have the "record" class

```
public class Class1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

An instance of this class, or an array of instances of this class, I want to fill with data from database Database1.sdf, table ProductTable:

```
Id int Primary
Name nvarchar 100
Category nvarchar 100
Price money
```

So I made

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductTable WHERE id=4");
cmd.Connection = conn;
Class1 row = cmd.
```

and there I simply don't know how to proceed. Similarly with

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductTable");
cmd.Connection = conn;
Class1[] rows = cmd.
```

Which is the preferred way to fetch the data objects from the database?

Comment: The preferred way is to use ORM such as NHibernate http://nhforge.org/ (something like doctrine in php). Your approach is good mostly for sample projects.

Comment: Or use LINQ to Entities, or LINQ to SQL...

Comment: use Entity Framework, it's a powerful opensource ORM

Comment: EF is great, but may be overkill for an introduction to reading/writing data in c#. Often it's better not to skip the basic functionality of the `System.Data` namespace. Look at using `SqlDataReader` to read the data. You can use an ORM, but it's a bit more to learn and it may be that you don't need this level of abstraction for your project. As Jon said, LINQ is also a good starting point. EF can always come later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your self a favor and learn to use an ORM of some sort, for a really lightweight and easy-to-use one, I recommend Dapper and you can do something like this:

```
        using (var sqlConnSource = new SqlConnection(SqlSource))
        {
            sqlConnSource.Open();
            var myProducts = sqlConnSource.Query<Class1>("SELECT * FROM Products").ToList();
            foreach (var p in myProducts)
            {
                //do something more useful here if you want
              Console.Writeline("The product name is:" + p.Name)

            }
        }
```

Comment: There must be a nicer syntax where you don't need to type some SQL string. That's half the point isn't it.

Comment: Yes, but with dapper that's the way you do it and that's why it so lightweight, you are running 'just above the metal', so to speak. If you want more abstraction, Entity framework (and others) would do it, but with more overhead (and more difficult to demonstrate in a 10 line snippet of code).

Answer (score 1):

If you want it without going for ORM/Entity framework, simply you can do it with C#,

```
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductTable WHERE id=@val", conn))
{
    //read search value from from text field
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val",<whateverthevalue>);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read()) //use while if you want to get multiple records 
     {
    Class1Obj.id= reader.GetString(0);
    Calss1Obj.Name= reader.GetString(1);
    .....
      }

    conn.Close();
}
```